# How to reference $< in Android.mk

Tags: android-ndk

I print `__FILE__` (the compile-time macro) when logging. `__FILE__` is the full path of the source file, and it takes up a lot of space in the logs. In the Linux build of my app I can do something like this:

CFLAGS += -DSHORTPATH="$(notdir $<)"

then print SHORTPATH instead of `__FILE__`. But when I try the same in Android.mk it doesn't work (SHORTNAME is the empty string, probably because $< is unset when notdir is invoked.)

Assuming this sort of thing is possible in the NDK, how to do it?

Thanks,

--Eric House